# Does StreamingOutput spawn a new thread to write to the output stream?

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

Let us say we have a web service like this:

//This code is taken from a stack overflow question

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response streamExample() {
  StreamingOutput stream = service.getStream();
  return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

Service class:

```
public class Service{

      public StreamingOutput getStream(){
            log.info("Going to start Streaming");
            StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
                writer.write("test");
                log.info("Inside streaming.");
                writer.flush();
           }
           };
           log.info("Finished streaming.");
           return stream;
      }
}
```

The output in the log file is:
Going to start Streaming.
Finished Streaming.
Inside streaming.

There are two questions I would like to ask regarding this:
1. Is there a new thread being created to stream the output for every request?
2. If there is a hibernate query that I would like to run inside the write method of streaming output how do I associate a session to this thread?